# Where to find the Rails API rdoc template

Tags: ruby, templates, rdoc

I'm trying to prettify my rdoc documentation, using version 3.5.3. I'm not a fan of the built-in darkfish theme, so I tried to find a way to replace it with the one used by the official Rails API documentation at http://api.rubyonrails.org/, but I've had no luck finding it in any readily available form. I've searched all over github, among other things.

What I've found so far is

- https://github.com/mislav/hanna

which might be slightly out of date, and it's fork

- https://github.com/rdoc/hanna-nouveau

Both are nice, but not quite what I want. So before I start fiddling with those templates, does anyone know if the template used by the Rails API docs is available as a gem somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like it. Ignore the instructions that say to do a `gem install horo --pre` -- that'll actually give you an older beta version. Just do `gem install horo` and you'll get the current 1.0.3 version (**Edit**: I sent a pull request to update the instructions, which has already been accepted).

https://github.com/tenderlove/horo

By the way, I found this by looking at the [Rails source code](http://github.com/rails/rails) and viewing the `Rakefile` to see the RDoc options. Specifically, line 67 shows `rdoc.options << '-f' << 'horo'`.

Comment: BTW I looked there too (railties-3.0.4), but all I found was 'rdoc.template = ENV['template'] if ENV['template']'... that didn't help me. Where exactly did you find it?

Comment: Line 67 of the Rakefile (NOT the Railties rakefile, the Rakefile in the root of the project)

Answer (score 4):

I know this is very late, but it looks like the new version of Rails uses something called sdoc, which enhances the output with JavaScript searching, and is a little cleaner IMO.  Doing a simple "gem install sdoc" will get what you need, then just use `rdoc.options << '-f' << 'sdoc'`.

The github project appears to be at https://github.com/voloko/sdoc/

By the way, thanks for the question!  Without the initial answer posted, I'd have never found where to look, and been stuck with that horrible darkfish theme for my own projects!